# Zend Framework on shared hosting with PHP as CGI

Tags: php, zend-framework, configuration, cgi, zend-autoloader

I have been reading a lot before coming to this situation of asking for help.
I have been speaking with the hosting company too about getting some help, but their technical support were as knowledgeable as I.

As many of the people around here writing on Zend Framework installation on a shared host, I have a deep problem with autoloading and class finding.

I have access to php.ini, .htaccess (obvious), the root directory and the public directory( of course).

The structure for my installation is the following:

```
/ - root, not accessible to public users) 
   /application
         /config
          /controller
          /model
          /view
          /forms
              /decorators
              /cache
              /view_compiles
        /layout 
  /library
      /Zend
      /(other libraries)
      /images
      /scripts
      /styles
 /public_html (public root)
       /css
       /js
       .htaccess (zend standard)
       index.php
```

in short, I use the standard Zend layout (as per Zend Tools).
So I have installed everything above the public area, and all the content of public is in the publicy accessible server.

On my local server, everything is working perfectly.
it runs from a folder inside the webroot and all is ok.

On the production server, PHP is installed as CGI, and there might be the problem.
First the SetEnv do not work anymore.
No matter what I do with the paths in index.php the auto-loader do not work.

When you start the app a login form must come on.
Due to the fact that the autoloader do not work,
the form cannot find the elements that have been created in a custome class, thus
the following message:

> Fatal error: Class 'Model_Utils_FormElements' not found in
>   /home/sites/ttonline.com/application/forms/Login.php on line 32

If I was to put a require_once (wich I do not want that solution), I then get an error that the composite decorator as not been found.

The entire system is working perfectly on my localhost...

I would appreciate if anybody could give me an input/ideas of the possible solution to the situation.

thx

Comment: Where is FormElements.php located? I do not see that in your layout.

Comment: FormElements.php is located under models/utils.

Comment: In the bootstrap there is a declaration for namespace Model_. pointing to models/utils.

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to the fact that it was developed on windows machine and deployed on a linux/unix machine. Windows is loose on the capitalization of words and directories.

Conclusion: Capitalization error.